# Cronjob wont run my python installed script command

Tags: python, shell, cron

I am running a command which was installed as a script of a python package i created.

I have a cronned_job_shell_script.sh file:

```
touch a.txt
my_script_command
```

where `my_scrip_command` was installed using `pip install my_py_package.tar.gz`

The cron line is:

```
0 * * * * cronned_job_shell_script.sh
```

If I run `cronned_job_shell_script.sh` from shell it works fine, running the python script also.

Even trying `env -i /bin/bash --noprofile --norc` first and then running the script works.

The problem is, when scheduled by cron, the file a.txt is touched but the script does not seem to run.

Comment: Have you tried `0 * * * * /bin/sh cronned_job_shell_script.sh`?

Comment: Where is `my_script_command`? Is it possible that it's on the PATH for your login sessions, but not on your default PATH (or root's default path, if this is a root cron rather than a user cron)?

Comment: Meanwhile, would it be acceptable to just put the absolute path `/opt/mystuff/bin/my_script_command` or whatever instead of relying on PATH?

Comment: @fedorqui tried it now, still does not work

Comment: @abarnert Solved it, the problem was that cron ran it as a root user. Write it down as an answer and I'll accept it so you get the points :)

Comment: I wrote the answer—but really, I think this is a sysadmin question, not a programming question, so it probably belongs on superuser rather than here.

Comment: you're right. I thought about moving it, but then you answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're putting this in the system crontab, which means it's being run by root, and root has a different `PATH` variable than your user. So, testing it in the shell (as you, not root) doesn't actually test the same thing.

The easiest solution is to just use the absolute path to the script—`/opt/mystuff/bin/my_script_command` instead of just `my_script_command`.